# Postfix : send and save (relay smtp)

Tags: postfix

I have two problems related to Postfix.

1. I have 4 local mailboxes on my mail server :

- qaz@example.com
- yhj@example.com
- qwe@example.com
- other@example.com

The mail is fetched via fetchmail and is split from the catchall mailbox qwe@example.com to local mailboxes.Everything that is not addressed to *qaz*, *yhj* and *qwe* should go to other.

I also have redirections set up on some addresses that are sent to *qwe*, but the forwarded emails come addressed as to the local admin of the given system
e.g. administrator@test.com forwards the email to qwe and comes as addressed to administrator@test.com.

I would like such emails to also fall into the other@example.com mailbox
but there are quite a lot of such addresses, some of which I do not remember. I would like each of these other emails to go to mailbox other .

The second problem is that I also have remote boxes on the same *example.com* domain that are not locally on the server.

When you try to send an e-mail to example@example.com which is a remote mailbox, the mail is automatically saved in the local other mailbox (I would like it to be automatically sent outside of local mailboxes).

main.cf

```
inet_interfaces                 = all
inet_protocols                  = ipv4
myhostname                      = mail.example.com
mydomain                        = example.com
myorigin                        = $mydomain
mydestination                   = localhost.local, localhost, $mydomain, example.com
mynetworks                      = 127.0.0.0/8

message_size_limit              = 40960000

relay_domains                   =
local_transport                 = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
local_recipient_maps            = $virtual_mailbox_maps

virtual_transport               = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps                = static:8
virtual_gid_maps                = static:8
virtual_minimum_uid             = 8
virtual_mailbox_base            = /SRV/Maildir/mailboxes
virtual_mailbox_domains         = pgsql:/SRV/Maildir/postfix/virtual_box_domain.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps            = pgsql:/SRV/Maildir/postfix/virtual_box_box.cf
#virtual_alias_maps              = pgsql:/SRV/Maildir/postfix/virtual_box_alias.cf
virtual_alias_maps              = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_limit           = 512000000

queue_directory                 = /var/spool/postfix
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_type                 = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path                 = private/auth
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
                                reject_unauth_pipelining,
                                reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                                permit_mynetworks,
                                permit_sasl_authenticated,
                                reject_unauth_destination,
                                reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
                                reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
                                permit
smtpd_sasl_security_options     = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes
relayhost = [example.example.com]:587
```

virtual

```
 qwe@example.com        qwe@example.com     
    yhje@example.com    yhj@example.com 
    qaz@example.com        qaz@example.com  
    other@example.com      other@example.com
    @example.com            other@example.com
```

fetchmailrc

set daemon    60
set no bouncemail
set postmaster qwe@example.com

```
    poll example.example.com with proto imap port 993
    envelope "Delivered-To:"
    localdomains example.com
    user "qwe@example.com" with pass "secret" is * here smtp localhost

          
           keep
           ssl
           sslproto tls1.2+
```

I tried changing mydestination from mydestination = localhost.local, localhost, $mydomain, example.com to mydestination =
While mail is sent outside local mailboxes, there is a problem with looping mails on the mailbox from which e-mails are downloaded via fetchmail.
Then there are also problems with forwarding emails locally, e.g. from the qaz@example.com mailbox to yhj@example.com.

I also tried adding to virtual_alias_maps virtual-regexp :

```
/.+@(.+)/ other@example.com
```

It is known that when trying to send to external addresses in domain example.com it ended up saving all emails in other@example.com